# Directive not working on chosen directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i wrote a simple directive like :

```
myApp.directive('input', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        //scope: false,
        link: function (scope, elem) {
            if (scope.lang && elem.attr('type') === 'text') {
                elem.attr('lang', 'fa');
                console.log(scope.lang);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

It's working fine, but it's not working on chosen input search ?
Any idea? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish really, but perhaps if you can show your markup it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Please post your html code as well, otherwise its hard to comment